# Making a flashing LED magnetic earring

Tags: led, infrared

I am interested in finding out if it is possible to take a simple flashing LED magnetic earring (sold as novelties all over) and either converting it or using the housing to then power an infrared LED at the brightest possible setting? Or any other small form, wearable device would also be acceptable.

[image: LED Earring]

Comment: Can you post a picture of one of these earrings?

Comment: And while you're at it, fix the title to be something meaningful.

Comment: More data needed. What for, how ling, what does it do, why, ... ? Makes it MUCH easier to answer well.

Comment: Do you know where I would get one of these magnetic LED lights from. I have found some that are 1.5cms long but need some that are slightly smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to change the LED in a flashing earring to IR.  No, it is very unlikely that this will result in the brightest possible output from the IR LED.  IR LEDs usually can handle higher currents than visible LEDs, and the necessarily small power source in a earring is unlikely to be able to source the higher power.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that you would be able to replace an LED in a flashing earring or similar toy with an IR LED with any worthwhile result:

- Flashing earrings and other wearables often have SMD LEDs. Desoldering one and then soldering an IR LED in its place is non-trivial.
- IR LEDs typically have a lower forward voltage compared to visible color LEDs. The chance of pushing the IR LED beyond tolerance is very high... but also see next point.
- Visible color LEDs are usually rated for lower current than IR LEDs. Flashing type toys I have seen depend on the internal resistance of the tiny battery to limit current to the LED(s), rather than using any current limiting resistor or other circuitry. This will inherently limit the IR LED current too much to result in any *"brightest possible setting"*

In short: Not worth it, but YMMV.

Comment: If the IR LED has lower voltage drop, and is rated for higher current, then that's perfect. The lower voltage drop will cause a higher current.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet ... which the battery will be unable to source, was my point.

Comment: Aah, ok. But 2. and 3. can't both be true. Either the battery will limit the current too much to get the maximum brightness, or the IR LED is pushed beyond its current rating.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet **Precisely**. That's why I put the rider "*but also see next point*" at the end of point 2: Either of those constraints being breached would leave an inoperative / insufficiently operative IR LED.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is probably going to be physically unsoldering the LED. Looking at this picture:

[image: LED Earring]

The LED looks like a tiny surface mount one, and also looks like it's encased in a dome of clear resin. Removing this LED would be next to impossible.

Other earrings seem to have other types of LED.

[image: LED earring]

These ones look more promising, but it's very hard to tell from the picture.

My advice would be to buy a few different types of earring, and take them round to your nearest electronic engineers / designers, (or [hackspace](http://hackspace.org.uk/view/Main_Page) if there's one near you), and ask them to have a look to see if changing the LED is plausible. If it is, pay them to do it.